# angular 2 - a css file error that is not in my html page

Tags: css, angular2-template

I will use the css files that I want to get from a ready-made template in the project but I get such an error .. there is no such css file!

[LOOK AT THE ERROR](https://image.ibb.co/hHw02G/j.jpg)

code

[html codes](https://image.ibb.co/mW6Wbb/code.jpg)

There is no such css file in my html page

Comment: It propably get loaded somewhere else, in angular this could be e.g in your component but there are many possibilities

Comment: I think I found the error...

<link href="../assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />  it's because style.css css file... but i do not understand :)